# Panel Regression with Repeated Dependent Variable

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am conducting **Fixed Effects Regression Analyses** (Panel Regression) to analyze **characteristics of firm-disclosures**. My dependent variable is a disclosure characteristic (e.g. length, sentiment, ..). Obviously, I have **one observation for each firm-year** (firm-level). However, my independent variables also include manager data (e.g. age). I have **data for multiple managers for each firm-year** (manager-level), which I all want to include.

Simplified Data:

[image]

As priorly described, the green **dependent variable (Length) is repeated** for the manager-level perspective. However, manager-level data vary within firm-years. Fixed Effects are included for years and firms.

From a statistical perspective - can I run such regression analyses? If not, what is a proper procedure?

Comment: One approach would be to bring the manager data to the same level as the firm data, e.g., by taking averages of the managers' age per firm-year. However, your inference would then be on this aggregated level of age.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I decided to focus on the CEO and drop other manager data! Best, M.